# Missing 2px in CSS calculations w/ Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a button nicely lined up with an input box in this fiddle here (I'm working in Safari right now )

http://jsfiddle.net/hNx6E/13/

However the height of the button does not add up to the height of the input.  Here are my calculations.

**Button Height** = Font Height + Padding Top + Padding Bottom + Border Top + Border Bottom =

16+8+8+1+1 = 34

**Input Height** = Height + Border Top + Border Bottom =

34+1+1 = 36

There is a missing 2px some where.

Note in the fiddle I do my normalization at the end and normalize all ( I think used elements ).

```
p , input, div, body
```

Also note in the fiddle that I have CSS normalization turned off b.c. I do it manually.

Fiddle quit responding but next I was going to try their normalization to determine if I left off some element I am un-aware of...up now...just checked the normalize box on the left but this did not change anything.

Right now i consider this a hack b.c I just changed my height by 2px to account for the missing pixels...but I'd like it working in a way I understand.

Comment: I would also add a reset css as seen here: 

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Are you talking about the POST button? Looks perfectly fine to me in Safari on Win. 18+8+8+1+1 = 36px

Comment: @Hiro Protagonist Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @Ana - it looks fine but the numbers "don't add up"

Comment: @Cymbals - I'm need to understand where this 2px is coming from...not add a bunch of CSS that might change the output it and not know how.

Comment: @troolee - no I did not...in Firefox the Button i actually 2px higher...accounting for a 4px offset that I don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: @Hiro - it would have addressed the line-height problem you were having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 34+1+1 = 36 // fixed

What? Input's width is 34px + 2px for border, that's 36px total. The next problem is `line-height`, which increases height of the button.

I set `line-height: 1em` for `#po_but` and `width: 32px` for `#po_in`, [see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hNx6E/17/). The heights now both have 34px.

Comment: what is 1em in pixels...maybe that is one issue...a default line-height...by the way firefox is 4px off instead of 2px off like safari.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `height` and `line-height` instead of `top/bottom padding` to allign vertically. So you get something like:

```
#po_but {
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

BTW your code looks OK in safari/chrome on mac.

Comment: It looks O.K. but the numbers don't add up.