# Missing 4px+ in CSS Calculations w/ FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

For this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hNx6E/13/

What I believe is going on is different browsers have different defaults for attributes I'm not aware I'm using.

This is frustrating b.c. when you inspect the HTML the defaults are not viewable nor are the attributes.

Is there a list of default attributes for browsers, particularly FireFox and Safari?

Where is it?

The button is 2px or more larger in height than the input box when I expect it to be 2px smaller in height.

What is the difference between a base, Firefox, and Safari?

I need to understand what these differences are and not just mask them with a large amount of CSS reset code.

Thanks

**Reference:**

[SO Similar Issue - Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582110/missing-2px-in-css-calculations-w-safari)

[W3 Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug in Firefox to look at the computed CSS attributes for the element? That should tell you what the padding/margin/width/etc. when it's not explicitly defined in the CSS.

Comment: No...good idea...once I get a chance...for the mean while it was the default ( and hidden ) line-height that was throwing things off.

Comment: Line Height Fix - http://jsfiddle.net/hNx6E/23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers are applying their own line-height to your buttons. Adding `line-height:16px;` fixes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/hNx6E/20/

Comment: thanks just figured this out from last post....I will set em to 1 though...a bit better solution.

Comment: Not sure if em 1 is going to help, if it does do tell me.

Comment: 1em works better because is relative to whatever font-size you set...yes it does work...I imagine I could have used 100% as well.

Comment: Great it does, thanks for the explanation. Indeed 1em is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try box-sizing if you mixing width/height with padding/border. it'll force the browser to take the width/height value.

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has some default styles we should override them first using CSS RESET and then style according to us.

add this code at start of ur stylesheet

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: "I need to understand what these differences are and not just mask them with a large amount of CSS reset code"

Comment: CSS resets are miserable anyway, adding all that pointless page weight and then having to go back and redefine nonsense like `b,strong { font-weight:bold; }`

Comment: you google about css reset it is standard followed by everybody to avoid browser inconsistencies. those inconsistencies are because every browser will have their own different default styles for all tags

Comment: CSS Resets are miserable?? If I could downvote that comment, I would! Why would you rather deal with each browser differently when you can build one product out the same for all of them, eliminating inconsistent styling? I'd say the 2KB is well worth it...

Comment: Because I'd rather consider the occasional inconsistency individually on its merits rather than adopt a scorched-earth policy of wiping out all CSS defaults (even obvious ones like b, strong or ol). Not only to you have to "reset the reset" in a dozen places (more work), CSS resets wipe out important definitions where you don't fully understand the ramifications, like the `outline` attribute that is important for accessibility with keyboard navigation. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/

Comment: Reset doesn't mean that you should reset everything. you can omit reset css for the things that are not necessary for you